# Boost based on indexed field

Tags: java, lucene

I have some fields that are ordered in the index (e.g. lexographical `String`s). I'd like to give a higher boost/score to the higher values.

**What is the preferred way to do this in Lucene 4?** (obtaining the exact value through a hit to the IndexCache is suboptimal)

(There are plently of Google hits for earlier versions of Lucene, but the API has changed substantially with great improvements to the indexing system.)

Comment: I assume simply sorting on the field's value would not be adequate?  Also, is it acceptable to use field-level (that is, index time) boosting for this?

Comment: I'm currently using index time boosting (but, for various reasons, this only works because we re-index regularly... e.g. to boost "recent" documents). I don't know what you mean by "sorting on the field's value". If there were a way to use the natural index order of the fields, that would be perfect: avoiding actually looking at the document is critical (as with any efficient Lucene query).

Comment: I've noted a dramatic slow-down in insertion speed when doing the index boosting. In Lucene 4, index-time boosting means looping through all the indexable fields and manually boosting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort on a fields value lexicographically by passing a [`Sort`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html) into your call to [IndexSearcher.search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Sort%29).

```
SortField primarySort = new SortField("field", SortField.Type.STRING);
Sort sort = new Sort(primarySort, SortField.FIELD_SCORE);
searcher.search(query, hits, sort);
```

That will sort, first, on the lexicographic ordering of the given field, then by relevance score.  You can add as many sort fields as you like when constructing your `Sort`.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting but too restrictive. I certainly don't want this one field to *dominate* the ordering of results. Is it possible to construct a `Sort` that could use the (reverse) natural ordering of selected fields to select the winner when several hits have the same score?

Comment: Yes.  The order of the arguments passed to `Sort` determines their precedence.  `new Sort(SortField.FIELD_SCORE, primarySort);` would sort by relevance first, then by the field value (if scores are equal).

Comment: this isn't exactly the answer I was looking for, but it is good enough for me to mark it as so: perhaps it will help others (I was really looking for a way to get a genuine score boost from the ordering, not some before/after the thought of scoring.)